# How should I attribute names to a list, to work with ggplot function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics

I created a list of lists, each one representing one variable by doing this:

```
names(needed_data) <- c(
  "Ano", "Casamentos Hungria", "Casamentos Eslovénia",
  "Casamentos Noruega", "Divórcios Hungria", 
  "Divórcios Eslovénia","Divórcios Noruega"
)
```

Then, I proceeded to use `needed_data` in a `ggplot` function, but when I write, for example `aes(x = "Ano", y = "Casamentos Hungria")`, I don't think R-Studio "understands" this code. How should I name the list, so that it works?

Comment: If someone could edit the question it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aes()` uses [tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) - try either

```
aes(x = Ano, y = `Casamentos Hungria`)
```

or

```
aes_string(x = "Ano", y = "`Casamentos Hungria`")
```

Comment: hm, appears another error unfortunatly:

 ("Error in parse(text = elt) : <text>:1:12: unexpected symbol").    

But is there another way of naming the list so that aes() recognises?

Comment: Can you include the `ggplot()` calls that are resulting in this error in your question?

Comment: ggplot(needed_data,aes_string(x="Ano",y="Casamentos Hungria"))+geom_point()

Comment: See my edit - let me know if that works